# How to test if a class is abstract in Typescript using Mocha?

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js

I don't even know if this makes sense as a test, but I was trying to test if some class `Component` was abstract in Typescript using Mocha by the only way I could think of:

```
expect( new Component() ).to.throw( new Error( "" ) );
```

however this gives me a compilation error that makes sense but breaks the test:

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'Component'.
```

Is there any way to correctly test this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to perform this check in a test suite?

Comment: There's no way that this breaks your test. This is a compilation error, meaning that you get it before you even run the test. There's no such thing as abstract classes in javascript.

Comment: @Louis I'm using one so I would like to keep everything centralized. But shouldn't I test it?

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes you're right I get as compilation Error. There are no abstract classes in JS but there are in TS. So your point is that I can never get to run any test before right?

Comment: My point is that there's no need to test for it. The compiler already checks that for you, so by the time you get to running your test, if the compilation process completed with no errors, then you can assume that this is not an issue. Tests are good for runtime problems, compile time problems are figured out by the compiler.

Comment: @NitzanTomer thank you. But it can compile if is a normal class - not abstract. What about that case?

Comment: I thought you wanna make sure that you never instantiate abstract classes..  If that's the case then it's not a problem with normal classes. Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes your assumption was correct. My point is to catch the case when I inadvertly make something like `new AbstractClass()` and it initializes without any error when it shouldn't.

Comment: So there's no need to test it, because the compiler will inform you about that in the form of a compilation error.

Comment: @NitzanTomer not if I forget to put `abstract` before class declaration

Comment: If you have an abstract method in a class but you haven't made the class abstract then the compiler will still complain. If the class isn't abstract and it has no abstract methods then it is indeed not abstract, and there's no way you can catch that (no compilation errors, no runtime errors and no way of testing it)

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes, in my case I have an abstract class declaration with no abstract methods and it compiles. Thanks a lot for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test for this. Abstract classes are compiled down to regular classes, and Mocha is a *runtime* assertion framework.